# Can I set the label of a url in a vcard with ruby gem vpim?

Tags: ruby, web, vcf-vcard

I'm making vcards with ruby and the gem 'vpim'
The cards I have contain a few urls. Currently when I import the generated cards into the contacts app on a mac all the urls are labeled after homepage:

Is there a way I could change that naming to something like "twitter" or "youtube" for example?

This defines the url in the generated vcf file:

```
URL:youtube.com/chelseafc
```

I create that this way:

```
maker.add_url("youtube.com/chelseafc")
```

And in the contacts app I see homepage: youtube.com/chelseafc
I would like to see youtube: youtube.com/chelseafc to make it more descriptive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example where I can see how I need to define what I'm looking for.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Doe;John;;;
FN:John Doe
ORG:Example.com Inc.;
TITLE:Imaginary test person
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:johnDoe@example.org
TEL;type=WORK;type=pref:+1 617 555 1212
TEL;type=CELL:+1 781 555 1212
TEL;type=HOME:+1 202 555 1212
TEL;type=WORK:+1 (617) 555-1234
item1.ADR;type=WORK:;;2 Example Avenue;Anytown;NY;01111;USA
item1.X-ABADR:us
item2.ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;3 Acacia Avenue;Newtown;MA;02222;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
NOTE:John Doe has a long and varied history\, being documented on more police files that anyone else. Reports of his death are alas numerous.
item3.URL;type=pref:http\://www.example/com/doe
item3.X-ABLabel:_$!<HomePage>!$_
item4.URL:http\://www.example.com/Joe/foaf.df
item4.X-ABLabel:FOAF
item5.X-ABRELATEDNAMES;type=pref:Jane Doe
item5.X-ABLabel:_$!<Friend>!$_
CATEGORIES:Work,Test group
X-ABUID:5AD380FD-B2DE-4261-BA99-DE1D1DB52FBE\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

Taken from here: http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-notes.html